# Is it necessary to perform sysfs_remove_file() when you're removing that entire kobject anyways?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, driver, sysfs

In the code for my Linux Kernel module, I create a `kobject`, which becomes a directory in the /sys/ directory, and then create a `sysfs` file in it. So it looks like /sys/KobjName/SysfsFile. This is the only file in that `kobject` directory, and both the `sysfs` file and the `kobject` are to be deleted after the `rmmod moduleX` command is executed.

Currently my clean_up code for `moduleX` looks like

```
static void cleanup(void)
{
    /* Remove test file */
    if (file_ok)
        sysfs_remove_file(kobj, &attributes.attr);

    /* Remove /sys/ddttest directory */
    if (kobj)
        kobject_put(kobj);
}
```

where `file_ok` is an integer of 0 or 1 representing if the `sysfs_create_file(kobj, &attributes.attr)` function executed corrected (e.g. a file is created).

My question now is if it is even necessary to remove the `sysfs` file before removing the `kobject`. When navigating the file system in the user space, one can simply delete a directory, and that will remove all the files within it. Is that the case with `kobject`file systems in the kernel space?

Comment: when calling `rmdir` the utility will complain and not remove the directory, if the directory is not empty.  so it might not work.

Comment: rather than using kobject_put() to reduce the usage count, it might be more reliable to use the function: `void kobject_del(struct kobject *kobj);`